# Django model fields: reference to self on default keyword

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've been having problems to understand this and to come up with a way of doing a reference to `self` inside the `default` keyword of a model field:

Here is what I have:

```
class Bank(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Account(models.Model):
    bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank, related_name="accounts")
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # This is the guy
    special_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='%s-%s' % (self.number, self.bank.number))
```

So I'm trying to access self inside the class definition, which seems to not work out because python doesn't know where self is since its not an object yet.

I've tried different things like:

```
special_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='%s-%s' % (number, bank.number))
```

But in this case it doesn't recognize `bank.number` because bank its only a property with `models.ForeignKey`.

I've tried also using a method inside the `Account` class:

```
def bank_number(self):
    return self.bank.number
```

and then:

```
special_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='%s-%s' % (number, bank_number()))
```

That was kinda dumb because it still needs self.
Is there a way I can do this?

**I need it to store the number inside the database, so using a method like this wont help:**

```
def special_number(self):
    return '%s-%s' % (self.number, self.bank.number)
```

Comment: What happens if you give number and bank.number default values too ? Try setting special_code in the save() method of the model class if is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'm going for a post_save checking special_code empty to then populate once only with the data I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to access self in the default callable. There's a couple of other approaches to set your field's value:

If you don't want the user to be able to change the value, override the model's save method and set it there.

If the default is just a suggestion, and you do want to allow the user to change it, then override the model form's `__init__` method, then you can access self.instance and change set the field's initial value.

Comment: I'm going for a post_save signal instead of overriding the save method, but its almost the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of specifying a default for the field you probably want to override the `save()` method and populate the field right before storing the object in the database. The `save()` method also has access to `self`. Here is an example in the docs for that:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods

Answer (score 2):

As already answered, override the `save()` method of your model to assign a value to `special_code`. The `default` option of a field is not meant to depend on other fields of the model, so this will not work.

Also, have a look at the `editable` option, if you don't want the field to be edited.

```
special_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, editable=False)
```

Will prevent the field to be rendered in ModelForms you create from the model.